# Calculate $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2z}}{z^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following complex integral  $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2z}}{z^2}dz$.

The second part can be solved by parameterizing $z$ to $e^{it}$, and the first part could be solved by Residue theorem on $e^{2z}$, giving $\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}=9/2$. But splitting it up like this is not correct, so how should one solve this?

Thanks

Comment: $\int fg\neq \int f \int g$ in general

Comment: Hint: what's the $1/z$ coefficient in $e^{2z}/z^2$? Or you could use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles).

Comment: The residue at infinity contains the  $1/z^2$, but how can that be used here with an exponential function in the numerator?

Comment: Applying Cauchy's derivative formula should work ( $4\pi i$ ...?).

Comment: Please outline in an answer.

Comment: Do you know that $$
f^{(n)} (0) = \frac{{n!}}{{2\pi i}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\frac{{f(z)}}{{z^{n + 1} }}dz} \;?
$$ Or can you tell the Laurent series of $e^{2z}/z^2$ about $z=0$? Btw J.G. was refering to "Limit formula for higher-order poles" in the Wikipedia and not to "Residue at infinity".

Comment: Yes, the limit formula for higher orders I am very familiar with, I will give that a try. Thanks

Comment: So you are saying (1)you do not know the formula mentioned by Gary and (2)you do not know how to do the integral by finding the residue of $e^{2z}/z^2$ at $z=0$?  Then I guess the only thing left is  parameterize by $e^{it}$ and do the resulting real integral (perhaps by parts).  **Do not** expect us to do this for you.

Comment: @GEdgar I am so sorry Edgar, but I am not a Professor like you, and I see that I shouldn't have asked that you did this for me, as a student.

Answer (score 1):

By Gary's proposition, I outline the use of the limit formula for higher order derivatives on the problem. The general formula is

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=z_0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}\Big[(z-z_0)^mf(z)\Big].
\end{equation}

The function in our problem has a pole at $z=0$ of order $2$, i.e., $m=2$. Thus,

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}\frac{e^{2z}}{z^2}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{1!}\frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}}\Big[(z-0)^2\frac{e^{2z}}{z^2}\Big]=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d}{dz}e^{2z}=\lim_{z\to 0}2e^{2z}=2.
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2z}}{z^2}dz=2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z=0}\frac{e^{2z}}{z^2}=4\pi i.
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that the residue would  be, by definition, the integral divided by $2\pi i$. So you have to multiply $2$ by $2\pi i$ to get the value of $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{2z}}{z^2}dz$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this Gary!

Comment: Also, as I mentioned in a previous question of yours, your notation for the residue is not quite correct. It is not the residue of $z_0$ but the residue of $f$ at $z_0$: $\operatorname{Res}_{z=z_0}f(z)$.

Comment: Corrected now .

Comment: $Res_{|z|=1}$ does not make any sense. Hold on, do not edit your answer. I will do it.

Comment: I see, corrected.